# Prove that given transformation in continuous spaces is real

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, analysis, linear-transformations

Let $f \in C([0,1])$ and define
$$J(f):[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \longmapsto \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$
Then prove that $J(f):C([0,1]) \rightarrow C([0,1])$ is linear.

What I've tried: To prove linearity we need to show that $J(\alpha a+\beta b)=\alpha J(a)+\beta J(b)$.

$$J(\alpha a+\beta b)=\int_0^{\alpha a +\beta b}f(t)dt=F(\alpha a +\beta b)-F(0)$$
Can I say that $F(\alpha a+\beta b)=\alpha F(a)+\beta F(b)?$

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to prove that $J$ itself is a linear map, not $J(f)$, i.e. instead of proving that $J(f)(\alpha a+\beta b)=\alpha J(f)(a) + \beta J(f)(b)$ (which is false), you want to prove that $J(\alpha f + \beta g)=\alpha J(f) + \beta J(g)$ for any $f,g\in C([0,1])$.